# Difference between "attribute" and "layout(location=x) in" in opengl

Tags: glsl

They both can transfer vertex data, but what is the difference between them?

Do them work in a similar way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`attribute` is a qualifier for input variables.

From the [OpenGL Wiki](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Type_Qualifier_(GLSL)) page:

> The attribute qualifier is effectively equivalent to an input qualifier in vertex shaders.

In other words, they're equivalent (`in` is the input qualifier), but do note that this applies to `attribute`:

> The following qualifiers are deprecated as of GLSL 1.30 (OpenGL 3.0) and removed from GLSL 1.40 and above.

The [`layout` qualifier](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Layout_Qualifier_(GLSL)) lets you specify the variable's locations directly, avoiding the need to use `glBindAttribLocation`, or these can be used to match variables from (e.g.) vertex shader to fragment shader instead of using name matching, among other uses.